# category and subcategory as a activity

Tags: android, listview

I'm implementing part of application where user is asked to select a category and than sub category and sub-sub category(category-->subcategory-->subsub category-->profila of company). Each category list is shown in ListView. Do I need to create seperate activity for each listView?

Comment: You can accomplish that with activity for category and then dialogs for subcategories

Comment: What do you mean by dialog, where do you need it? Being more specific, after clicking a row in the listview you are going to subcategory list which also is shown in a listview.